# Cannot references elements of xml file

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I've been playing around with some government data trying to extract elements of the xml file they provide via python

Below is a sample of one of the products - Essentially what im trying to do is pull out data from HospitalCover i.e if each particular service is covered or not.

```
<Product
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ProductCode="J7/WAYB20" ProductItemID="024D633D-C67E-4609-B51D-DB7D4DD3D8A5" ProductID="95ddc834-6cce-4c6e-a28a-020cadd22b40" FundItemID="63328fd4-b6b7-441e-a4fe-bb1df2e3eedf" Status="Published" StatusDate="2020-10-01T00:00:55.6" DateModified="2020-08-10T11:35:41.473" DateCreated="2020-08-10T11:35:41.3746927" DateApproved="2020-08-10T11:45:41.283" PublishDate="01-Oct-20 00:00" SchemaVersion="3.0"
xmlns="http://admin.privatehealth.gov.au/ws/Schemas" xsi:schemaLocation="http://admin.privatehealth.gov.au/ws/Schemas PHOLSchema-V3.0.xsd">
<FundCode>CBH</FundCode>
<ProductGroupCode>J7</ProductGroupCode>
<Name>LiveLife (Gold)</Name>
<ProductType>Combined</ProductType>
<ProductURL xsi:nil="true" />
<PHISURL xsi:nil="true" />
<FundsProductCode xsi:nil="true" />
<ProductStatus>Closed</ProductStatus>
<Corporate Atomic="true" />
<OnlyAvailableWith Atomic="true">
    <NotApplicable xsi:nil="true" />
</OnlyAvailableWith>
<DateValidFrom xsi:nil="true" />
<DateValidTo xsi:nil="true" />
<DateIssued>2020-10-01</DateIssued>
<State>WA</State>
<Scale>Couple</Scale>
<Excesses ExcessType="None" Atomic="true" />
<CoPayments CoPaymentType="Limited" Atomic="true">
    <Shared>70</Shared>
    <SharedMax>420</SharedMax>
    <Private>70</Private>
    <PrivateMax>420</PrivateMax>
    <DaySurgery>70</DaySurgery>
    <AnnualMax>840</AnnualMax>
</CoPayments>
<MedicareLevySurchargeExempt>true</MedicareLevySurchargeExempt>
<PremiumNoRebate>602.9</PremiumNoRebate>
<PremiumHospitalComponent>401.93</PremiumHospitalComponent>
<AddOns />
<Brands />
<HospitalCover AccidentCover="true" BasedOnID="">
    <HospitalTier>Gold</HospitalTier>
    <AgeBasedDiscount Available="true" AvailableForTransferee="true" />
    <Accommodation>PrivateOrPublic</Accommodation>
    <HospitalPercent xsi:nil="true" />
    <LimitHospitalDays xsi:nil="true" />
    <MedicalServices>
        <MedicalService Title="AssistedReproductive" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="BackNeckSpine" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="Blood" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="BoneJointMuscle" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="BrainNervousSystem" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="BreastSurgery" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="Cataracts" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="ChemotherapyRadiotherapyImmunotherapy" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="DentalSurgery" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="Diabetes" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="Dialysis" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="DigestiveSystem" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="EarNoseThroat" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="Eye" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="GastrointestinalEndoscopy" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="Gynaecology" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="HeartVascular" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="HerniaAppendix" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="HospitalPsychiatric" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="ImplantationHearingDevices" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="InsulinPumps" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="JointReconstructions" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="JointReplacements" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="KidneyBladder" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="LungChest" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="MaleReproductive" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="MiscarriageTerminationOfPregnancy" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="PainManagement" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="PainManagementWithDevice" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="PalliativeCare" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="PlasticReconstructiveSurgery" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="PodiatricSurgery" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="PregnancyBirth" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="Rehabilitation" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="Skin" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="SleepStudies" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="TonsilsAdenoidsGrommets" Cover="Covered" />
        <MedicalService Title="WeightLossSurgery" Cover="Covered" />
    </MedicalServices>
    <WaitingPeriods>
        <WaitingPeriod Unit="Month" Atomic="true" Title="SubAcute">2</WaitingPeriod>
        <WaitingPeriod Unit="Month" Atomic="true" Title="PreExisting">12</WaitingPeriod>
        <WaitingPeriod Unit="Month" Atomic="true" Title="PregnancyBirth">12</WaitingPeriod>
        <WaitingPeriod Unit="Month" Atomic="true" Title="Other">2</WaitingPeriod>
    </WaitingPeriods>
    <OtherProductFeatures>Co-payments do not apply for any dependant children on the policy. Gap Assist benefit of $200 per person per calendar year.</OtherProductFeatures>
</HospitalCover>
<GeneralHealthCover BasedOnID="">
...
```

The issue is that I dont understand how i can reference it. If for example i run `root[0][21].tag` I'm returned `{http://admin.privatehealth.gov.au/ws/Schemas}Brands`. However running `root[0][22].tag` which is what id expect to return HospitalCover actually returns `{http://admin.privatehealth.gov.au/ws/Schemas}GeneralHealthCover`, completely skipping over hosptialCover and I'm wondering why that would be the case / how i can go about referencing these elements.

Edit:

For any particular medical service ie 'AssistedReproductive' i'd like to be able to see  whether its covered or not covered.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show what exactly is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to approach it, but since you are dealing with xml, the most effective way is to use xpath:

```
from lxml import etree
services = """[your xml above]"""

doc = etree.XML(services)
for service in doc.xpath('//*[local-name()="MedicalService"]'):
    print(service.attrib['Title'],": ",service.attrib['Cover'])
```

Output [note: in your xml, all services are covered]

```
AssistedReproductive :  Covered
BackNeckSpine :  Covered
Blood :  Covered
BoneJointMuscle :  Covered
BrainNervousSystem :  Covered
BreastSurgery :  Covered
```

etc.